# Give username explicitly when connecting to GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

Hi I have the problem that GitLab doesn't allow me to fetch/pull things (from my own repo) because it is confused about my username (gives the wrong result for `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`). I have my public-key uploaded.

So how does GitLab associate a username with the public-key that is uploaded? Can I give the right username explicitly when fetching?

Comment: If you have multiple keys you need to [configure SSH to use the proper key for every `Host`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh-keys%5D+multiple+accounts). Hint: you can use multiple different `Host`s with the same `HostName`. After that you need to configure Git to pass the proper `Host` to SSH.